# Can I travel to Poland to my husband without a Schengen visa or residence card?

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, south-african-citizens

I'm a South African living in Britain with my husband who is Polish. My visa has expired already, and I have not applied for my residence card yet.

My husband has travelled to Poland to be with his family for Christmas. Would I be able to travel to Poland to meet him there without me having my residence card?
I was told by a friend that I could travel if I have my marriage certificate on hand: is there any truth in that?

Answer (score 8):

In short, no, but you should be able to get a Schengen visa without charge and quickly.

South Africans require a visa to enter the Schengen area.  Visa nationals are exempted from this requirement *if they have a residence card indicating that they are a family member of an EU/EEA national.*

Family members without such a card still enjoy the right of freedom of movement under EU law, when traveling with or joining their EU/EEA family member, *except that they still require a visa.*

Since you don't yet have that card, you need a visa.

The visa is supposed to be issued free of charge, and through an expedited process.  Your best course of action, therefore, is probably to apply for a visa at the Polish consulate.

Comment: Would the fact that the OP is overstaying in the UK have any effect?

Comment: @CMaster as the spouse of an EU citizen, OP can't really overstay, she can only be fined for failing to register.